# Why won't my express route functions fire their callback functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, passport.js

I've built some routes out with passport authentication and none of them are firing their callbacks at all. The routes are working, but nothing is logging to console for me to debug. Can anyone help me figure out why? Below is part of my server.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://localhost:3000',
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type,Authorization",
    credentials: true
}));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log('Welcome')
});

app.get("/auth/yahoo", passport.authenticate("yahoo"), (req, res) => {
    console.log('Authenticating..')
  });

app.get("/auth/yahoo/redirect",
  passport.authenticate("yahoo", {
      failureRedirect: "/auth/login/failed" 
    }),
    function(req, res) {
        console.log('Redirecting..')
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/profile');
    }
);

app.get("/auth/login/failed", (req, res) => {
    console.log('Authentication Failed')
});

const port = 9000;

const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./security/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./security/cert.pem')
};

const server = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)
    .listen(port, () => {
        console.log('server running at ' + port)
});
```

Thanks!